# Why do some attributes in Xml deserialization always return null?

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization, .net-2.0

I want to deserialize the following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<function xmlns="urn:google.com" >
  <file>my.xml</file>
  <name>My</name>
  <arguments>
    <argument type="int" object="a"/>
    <argument type="char" object="b"/>
  </arguments>
  <return_type>int</return_type>
  <sql>MySql</sql>
  <content>xyz</content>
</function>
```

.
So, I have written the following code:

```
public class Argument 
{
    [XmlAttribute("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("object")]
    public string Object { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("function", Namespace = "urn:google.com")]
public class Function
{
    [XmlElement("file")]
    public string File { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("sql")]
    public string Sql { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("return_type")]
    public string ReturnType{ get; set; }

    [XmlElement("arguments")]
    public List<Argument> Arguments { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("content")]
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public static Function Deserialize(string fullPath)
    {
        XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Function));
        TextReader reader = new StreamReader(fullPath);
        object obj = deserializer.Deserialize(reader);

        Function f = (Function)obj;
        reader.Close();

        return f;
    }
}
```

The code is working except `Type` and `Object` properties of each `Argument` are always `null`.

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: did you try giving the namespace to each of the `XmlElementAttribute`s?

Comment: @DanielA.White, Yes. I gave a try, and that didn't work.

Comment: Did you try : [XmlElementArray("arguments")]

Comment: @jdweng, No. This is .net2.0 code.

Comment: Why should net 2.0 make a difference?  You have two tags : arguments and argument but only one class Argument.  Specifying you have an XmlArray will allow the two tags to be handled with only one class.  Otherwise, you will need a separate class for the tag arguments and the tag argument

Comment: @jdweng, 1st you wrote `XmlElementArray` rather than `XmlArray`. Now you are telling me to fix something which is not broken.

Comment: XmlElementArray was a typo.  You need to use XmlArray or create two classes.  It is broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
[XmlElement("arguments")]
public List<Argument> Arguments { get; set; }
```

to

```
[XmlArray("arguments")]
[XmlArrayItem("argument")]
public List<Argument> Arguments { get; set; }
```